# Why are my concrete water tanks not retaining water?

Tags: concrete, leak

I have concrete  water  tanks,  where  I  grow  ornamental  fish.

Recently  on  draining the  tanks  to  clean,  I observed  that  they  do  not  retain  the water.  The  tanks  drain  over  time, but there are no  visible  leaks  noticed.

Comment: Concrete is porous. It is not a water tight material.  The only way to make it water tight is to treat it either on the inside (where the fish live) or on the outside with some kind of waterproofing material.

Comment: @MatthewPK Look at the edit history

Answer (score 3):

Concrete is porous. It is not a water tight material. The only way to make it water tight is to treat it either on the inside (where the fish live) or on the outside with some kind of waterproofing material.